# Highlight selected item

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview

hello i got strange issue **i want highlight selected item in listview**

heres my xml files

selected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/header" />
 <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/selected" />
</selector>
```

listitem_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/android:transparent" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/selector" />
</selector>
```

activity that host ListView

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
android:background="@drawable/listitem_background" >

...

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/carsList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/carConfirmBtn"
    android:layout_below="@id/carSelect"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/small"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/small"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/selector" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and finally fragment of code that define that

```
carsList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
carsList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
                long arg3) {
   carsList.setSelection(pos);
 }
});
```

pls help

Comment: can u please give image of you want to display...

Comment: try removing `android:listSelector="@drawable/selector"` from `ListView`..

Comment: i update question to keep it simple what i mean :)

Answer (score 0):

in your get view, before returning view, add this code :-
Whatever row you want to highlight , modify the if statement. Translate highlights the selected row for 5 seconds(you can change it) and the colors slowly fades off to white. check the xml

```
            if(position == 0){
                viewHolderThubnail.relImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.translate);
                TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) viewHolderThubnail.relImage.getBackground();
                transition.startTransition(1000); // 1000 is in milliseconds
                highlightPosition =-1;
            }else{
                /*TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) viewHolderThubnail.relImage.getBackground();
                transition.startTransition(1000);*/
                viewHolderThubnail.relImage.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
            }
```

translate.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
          <!-- The drawables used here can be solid colors, gradients, shapes, images, etc. -->
          <item android:drawable="@drawable/new_state" />
          <item android:drawable="@drawable/original_state" />
   </transition>
```

new_state.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#92BCE7"/>
</shape>
```

original_state.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
</shape>
```

relImage is the row if your listview you want to highlight.